# How to return the for loop values in python and access them in other script

Tags: python, scripting

From the below function, I am able to print the information of `crew_filter` and `node`. But I need help on returning those values to the target script. And also how can I access them in the target script?

```
def getValuesForNode(self):
   for crew_filter, node in self.getNodes():
       print crew_filter, node
```

Note: As `crew_filter` and `node` will have multiple values, I need to store them in a tuple or dictionary.

Comment: Why not just `return self.getNodes()`? In fact, why have the function at all?

Comment: Are you miporting this module into another script or does it run as its own process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class `Test` is written in the script `test.py`.

## test.py

```
class Test:
    def get_values_for_node(self):
        test_data = (
            (1, 2),
            (3, 4),
            (5, 6)
        )
        for crew_filter, node in test_data:
            yield crew_filter, node
```

Then you can access your value by the generator defined above in another script, for example `foo.py`:

## foo.py

```
from test import Test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    for crew_filter, node in test.get_values_for_node():
        print('{0} - {1}'.format(crew_filter, node))
```

## Output

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
```

You can replace the var `test_data` with your data source, either tuple or dict, if you wanna iterate a dict you have to do it like following:

```
class Test:
    def get_values_for_node(self):
        test_data = {
            'id':1,
            'name': 'tom',
            'age': 23
        }
        for crew_filter, node in test_data.items():
            yield crew_filter, node
```

## Output

```
id - 1
name - tom
age - 23
```

If you are unfamiliar with the usage of the `yield` or the concept of `generator`, you can view this page:

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: The solution perfectly fits my query. Ur amazing.